# Cross-Origin issue with getViews()

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have been working in my free time to create a Firefox WebExtensions based add-on that essentially reads the page, opens a local HTML, submits a form on the HTML page to navigate to a new URL but I am running into issues with `chrome.extension.getViews()` once my opened page changes URLs.

If I reuse `getViews()` I receive the following error:

> Not allowed to define cross-origin object as property on [Object] or [Array] XrayWrapper

I tracked this down and find it happens once my local HTML navigates away. How should I be interacting with my opened web page to get around this issue?

Below is a small recreation I hacked together with timeouts (not my actual project, just to show the problem):

## background.js

```
var views;

function openMyPage() {
  console.log("injecting");
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: chrome.extension.getURL("content_scripts/my-page.html"),
        active: false
    }, function(tab) {
        chrome.windows.create({
            tabId: tab.id, 
            type: "normal",
            state: "maximized"
        }, function(window) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                views = chrome.extension.getViews();
                for(var i = 0; i < views.length; i++)
                    console.log("window location: " + views[i].location + " view id: " + i);
                views[1].example();
                setTimeout(function(){
                    for(var i = 0; i < views.length; i++)
                        console.log("window location: "+views[i].location+" view id: " + i);
                }, 5000);
            }, 2000);

        }); 
    });
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(openMyPage);
```

## my-page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="my-page.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <h1>It's my page!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

## my-page.js

```
console.log("loaded in my-page");

function example() {
    document.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you found out, the `window` object you were provided is no longer valid once you navigate away from the page that the `window` object conained.  The `window` object was valid while the window you opened was displaying the same page as it was when you made the call to [`extension.getViews()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/extension/getViews). It became invalid as soon as you navigated away from that page.  The old `window` object would have been invalid, even if you had navigated to another page within your extension, because a new `window` object would have been created for the new page. However, if the new page was from within your extension, you would have been able to obtain a new `window` object with a new call to `extension.getViews()`.

Once you navigate away from a page that is from within your extension, [`extension.getViews()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/extension/getViews) will no longer find the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object for the popup/tab.

Once you navigate away from the URL which is to a page within your own extension, you should be interacting with the page the same way you would with any other content: with a [content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts).

[`extension.getViews()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/extension/getViews) will get `window` objects for:

> Returns an array of the [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) objects for each of the **pages running inside the current extension**. This includes, for example:
>
> - the background page, if one is defined
> - any popup pages, if defined and loaded
> - any options pages, if defined and loaded
> - any browser tabs that **host content packaged with the add-on**

Comment: I guess I understand the reason it fails but does it make sense `extension.getViews()` becomes completely broken as soon as an extension page navigates away? I found I couldn't utilize content scripts with my local HTML pages so I opted to this. I'll probably rework things to inject the form into the current web page and go from there.